# How can i add React loading spinner when item is fetching from database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Here is, my code. i want to add a spinner when data is loading then after finish loading display the data.

```
  {/* product section  */}
  <section className="container mx-auto my-5 row">
      <h6 className="text-center">WANT TO SEE</h6>
      <h2 className="text-center mb-5">Our Services</h2>
    {
      Products.slice(0,6)?.map((product) => {
        return <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>;
      })
    }
  </section>
```

**And This is the custom hook**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const LoadProducts = () => {
    const [Products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/products')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>setProducts(data))
    },[]);
    return [Products, setProducts]
}
export default LoadProducts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const LoadProducts = () => {
    const [Products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    useEffect(()=>{
        setLoading(true);
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/products')
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .then(data=>setProducts(data))
        .finally(()=>setLoading(false))
    },[]);
    return [Products, setProducts, loading]
}
export default LoadProducts;
```

Note the custom hook now returns [Products, setProducts, loading].

Now you can add some conditional code to your JSX that shows a loading spinner while loading is true

```
  {/* product section  */}
  <section className="container mx-auto my-5 row">
      <h6 className="text-center">WANT TO SEE</h6>
      <h2 className="text-center mb-5">Our Services</h2>
    {loading ? (
      <MyLoadingSpinner/>
     ) : (
      Products.slice(0,6)?.map((product) => {
        return <Product key={product._id} product={product}></Product>;
      })
    )}
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this but you can customize it to your needs. The trick is really to create a loading state which initially will be false. When you start calling your api, you will set your loading to true. Once you either get a response or fail you set it to false.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
        setPosts(json);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <div>I am loading</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <p>{post.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```